# Issues running Mobile Emulators in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, virtual-machine, windows-10, emulation

I am trying to test an app with the Mobile Emulators in VS2015 on a Windows 10 Virtual Machine.

The issue I am running into is once I start the emulator, it is stuck on starting (found via Hyper-V Manager) and I cannot stop the emulator once it is in this state. If I try to run the app again, with the mobile emulator that's status is stuck on [Starting...], I receive a "memory" issue (32775).

So I guess my overall question is how to I successfully start a mobile emulator and how do I stop these that are currently running? I have attempted disabling Hyper-V (which caused a lot of issues trying to re-enable it). I have also tried a few other "solutions" I have found online and none of them have worked so far.

Thanks for any help/support.

EDIT - I have went through the BIOS and verified that VT-X is turned on and I have made sure that the I/O verification option in Driver Verifier for all drivers is turned off. I have also removed any anti-virus software and the issue still remains.

Comment: Have you checked these two similar cases: [Windows Phone Emulator: Error code 32775](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/be73ddc6-4116-4552-aca7-7332a19d4601/windows-phone-emulator-error-code-32775?forum=wpdevelop) and [Windows Phone 8 Emulator Couldn't change memory of the virtual machine: Error code 32775 \[solved\]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba1074fb-6873-4b26-b27b-d4a733f03f0b/windows-phone-8-emulator-couldnt-change-memory-of-the-virtual-machine-error-code-32775-solved?forum=wptools)?

Comment: I have tried both of these methods and neither have worked for me.